# How to get 'four corner' alignment with floated divs

Tags: html, css, properties

Ok so my project requires my divs to be floated because I would like to place text neatly to the side of them. I can get my divs to float left and right as needed, but as you see from the snippet(even though it's not what you'd get from a browser since the dimensions are off), the two divs at the bottom I need to be near the top in order to make a perfect scquare with the two left-floated divs. Below is what I'm looking for:

[image: a picture of a sketch of a website]

```css
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
#centerbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 150px);
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
}
#centerbar h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: courier;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: white;
}
#container {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -150px;
  width: 100%;
}
#container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
#content {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.box {
  height: 200px;
}
.fltlt {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
.fltrt {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Works</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div id="centerbar">
    <h1>Sample Layout</h1>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="gold.jpg" alt="The Color Gold" class="fltlt">
      <p>This is some sample text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="grey.jpg" alt="The Color Grey" class="fltlt">
      <p>This is some sample text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="orange.jpg" alt="The Color Orange" class="fltrt">
      <p>This is some sample text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="red.png" alt="The Color Red" class="fltrt">
      <p>This is some sample text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="sub">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="sub">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="sub">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to float the box containers too not just the img

Comment: Is something like this what you're looking for?
https://jsfiddle.net/hv0ovfqn/

Comment: @Hamilton Lucas Yep that's it thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to not use `float` for layout, and since you started out with `flex`, use it all the way.

*Bonus: A clean, simple and readable structure of both CSS and markup.*

```css
.container .row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row .box {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.box img {
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSr2zmmalj8xwazqph9jB97VW8MgfrfJ_ThJt9iTGKGMNl-7dp7mKnfvg4" alt="">
        <p>Some paragraph here</p>
    </div> 
    <div class="box">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSr2zmmalj8xwazqph9jB97VW8MgfrfJ_ThJt9iTGKGMNl-7dp7mKnfvg4" alt="">
        <p>Some paragraph here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSr2zmmalj8xwazqph9jB97VW8MgfrfJ_ThJt9iTGKGMNl-7dp7mKnfvg4" alt="">
        <p>Some paragraph here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSr2zmmalj8xwazqph9jB97VW8MgfrfJ_ThJt9iTGKGMNl-7dp7mKnfvg4" alt="">
        <p>Some paragraph here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not really fully understanding flex box it seems. When you take off the container div it only goes in one column. Why is this?

Comment: @Shinji-san If you remove the `container` div you need to change the `.container .row {...}` rule to `.row {...}` because the `.container` class is used target a `.box` child class

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you are looking for(I made it from the start):

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.container .flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.container p {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box">
    <div class="flex">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSr2zmmalj8xwazqph9jB97VW8MgfrfJ_ThJt9iTGKGMNl-7dp7mKnfvg4" alt="" width="100">
      <p>Some paragraph here</p>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="box">
    <div class="flex">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSr2zmmalj8xwazqph9jB97VW8MgfrfJ_ThJt9iTGKGMNl-7dp7mKnfvg4" alt="" width="100">
      <p>Some paragraph here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="box">
     <div class="flex">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSr2zmmalj8xwazqph9jB97VW8MgfrfJ_ThJt9iTGKGMNl-7dp7mKnfvg4" alt="" width="100">
      <p>Some paragraph here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="box">
     <div class="flex">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSr2zmmalj8xwazqph9jB97VW8MgfrfJ_ThJt9iTGKGMNl-7dp7mKnfvg4" alt="" width="100">
      <p>Some paragraph here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a question. How do you get the actual boxes to wrap without declaring wrap in the flex?

Comment: This is because flex, if you do not set flex direction, it sets flex-direction: row by default, and it puts all elements in the same line. You got it!

Comment: So in this example they're centering relative to the 'box' div, right?

Comment: Something like that! Center position of paragraph and image is just because their parent with the class name flex, which some elements are inherited from their parent with the class box.

Comment: If you set height to a parent element, and if you have a paragraph or some other text within that parent, you can center vertically with line-height too. So, in our case, height of box is for example: 200px, and if you set this element line height same as height, your text would position vertically in center.